# How can I use local absolute path as a src attribute for an image

Tags: javascript, html, path, local, absolute

I'm trying to make the source of my image like this

```
<img id="testImage" src="C:\images\1.jpg">
```

but this doesn't work, i also tried changing all the \ with / but it gave me the same not working result

the reason for this is that i want to make a web page that can read from many local folders on my HDD with javascript. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an absolute URI to a local file, then you need to use [the file uri scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

In your case, you are probably looking for `file:///c:/images/1.jpg`.

Browsers tend to put heavy restrictions on accessing local files. You may file that just trying to show an image will run into a security policy (especially if the HTML document is served over HTTP). [Trying to access them with JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs) is even more likely to run into problems.

Comment: I swear that i tried this but there must be something wrong when i used this but when you mentioned it again I tried it again and it worked